# What is being deleted?

Tags: visual-foxpro

I'm going through some Visual Foxpro 7.0 which is new to me. I'm having a bit of trouble deciphering a DELETE command inside a DO WHILE with two different work areas.

I'm just not clear on what is actually being deleted. When the DELETE command is issued I'm using Work Area 1 but I'm not looping through any records. If the DELETE command IS being used against tblpay (Work Area 1) then it seems that it's deleting the record that was just inserted which makes no sense. Can someone clue me please?

```
select 1 (tblpay)
USE tblpay

select 2 (tblfac)
USE tblfac
GOTO top

DO WHILE NOT EOF()
    lcfy = fy
    lcindex_no = index_no
    lcpca = pca
    lnpys = padl(alltrim(str(cum_pys)),13,' ')
    select 1 (tblpay)
    LOCATE FOR fy = lcfy AND index_no = lcindex_no AND pca = lcpca
    IF NOT FOUND()
        INSERT INTO tblpay(exp_1,fy,exp_3,exp_4,exp_5,exp_6,index_no,exp_8,pca,cum_pys,reversal) ;
            values('805',lcfy,SPACE(37),lcdoc_date,lccurdoc,'00',lcindex_no,'99802',lcpca,lnpys,'R')
        DELETE
    ENDIF
    select 2 (tblfac)
    SKIP
ENDDO
```

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly the code you show is not very clear.

Some suggested changes:

```
select 1 (tblpay)  
USE tblpay
```

should be

```
USE tblpay IN 0  && Open table tblpay into next available workspace
```

and

```
select 2 (tblfac)
USE tblfac
```

should be

```
USE tblfac IN 0  && Open table tblfac into next available workspace
```

Then you would no longer have to remember **SELECT 1** or **SELECT 2** - Now what did I have in #1 or #2?
Instead you would choose the table it by its **Alias** such as:    **SELECT tblpac**

The rest of the code doesn't make much sense either.
* You choose table   **tblfac** and SCAN its records for values
* Then you go to table **tblpay** and attempt to LOCATE one or more specific records
*  If the **tblpay ** record is NOT FOUND, you then use the values from **tblfac** (and other info) and INSERT a new record into **tblpay** using a SQL Command (you could have also used the VFP commands: **APPEND BLANK** followed by a **REPLACE**)
* The DELETE that follows that will Delete the table record that it is currently pointing to - however the way your code is written it might not be what you want.

The way it looks, it seems like if you have NOT FOUND() a matching record in **tblpay** your record pointer is still pointing to that table, but it is now at the EOF() (End Of File) and not to any actual record.   And an attempt to Delete it will not do anything.

In your VFP Development mode, you should use the Debug methods to actually 'see' which table table record pointer is 'looking' at and which record.
To do that you might want to use ** SET STEP ON**  in the following manner.

```
IF NOT FOUND()
    INSERT INTO tblpay(exp_1,fy,exp_3,exp_4,exp_5,exp_6,index_no,exp_8,pca,cum_pys,reversal) ;
        values('805',lcfy,SPACE(37),lcdoc_date,lccurdoc,'00',lcindex_no,'99802',lcpca,lnpys,'R')
    SET STEP ON  && Added Here for Debug Purposes ONLY
    DELETE
ENDIF
```

Then when you execute the code in the VFP Development mode and execution hits that line, it will Suspend execution and open the Debug TRACE window - thereby allowing you to investigate the record pointer, etc.

Good Luck

Comment: Just to clear myself.. I didn't write this code. It's in 300 pages of text documents from which I'm working. I don't even have a project that I could use to debug this and see for myself. I will review what you said and see what I can come up with. Thank you!

Comment: Just to add I'm converting this code to vb.net and SQL so I was just trying to figure out if the DELETE was against the current record in the DO WHILE or the INSERT record. Thanks again!

Comment: It is not correct that the pointer is at EOF when delete executed. It is on the newly inserted record. Thus delete is deleting the inserted record.

Comment: And as a sidenote, insert and append blank/replace are different. Latter is not recommended to use on multiuser environments.

Answer (score 1):

What Dhugalmac has said is partially correct but not entirely. If the record searched is not found, then you are inserting a record and then you are deleting that newly inserted record. Pointer is NOT at EOF but at that new record.

As Dhugalmac said, do not use work area numbers but aliases instead. Above code is not the real code, it wouldn't run without an error.

If you are using this code and the text it is in for learning, immediately stop reading it and dump it away. The code is terrible and doesn't sound to have a purpose (besides having errors).

If your intent is to learn how to delete from VB.Net, just use VFPOLEDB and a DELETE - SQL command with ExecuteNonQuery (just as you would do against SQL server, PostgreSQL, MySql ... any ANSI database). With VB.Net, most of the xbase commands have no place (neither those do while ... skip ...enddo  - even you wouldn't use it from within VFP).

Comment: It's real code and it runs without error I just don't have the source project. I'm converting the app to vb.net and sql and needed to understand what that DELETE command was actually deleting. I won't be making any changes to the Foxpro stuff. Thank you.

Comment: It IS not the real code. Just try copy/pasting and running it from within VFP. It simply has syntax errors.
DELETE command is deleting the record inserted as I already said. That code has no purpose (the only very slight possibility is to insert and immediately mark the inserted records as deleted on a tricky purpose).

Comment: You are saying it is real. Have you ever tried to run that code (really). I wonder in which foxpro version it would run without any errors.